# How to get earliest date From RDD[String, List[java.sql.date]], Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have the below RDD, t1RDD2, only the first five rows present:

```
(000471242-01,CompactBuffer(2012-05-07, 2006-11-15, 2014-10-08, 2010-05-20))
(996006688-01,CompactBuffer(2011-01-18, 2005-08-19, 2008-08-27, 2014-09-05, 2006-06-26, 2012-05-10, 2013-11-22, 2005-10-14, 2007-03-26, 2007-05-17, 2010-05-19, 2008-07-11, 2009-03-09))
(788000995-01,CompactBuffer(2006-01-06, 2013-05-01))
(525570000-01,CompactBuffer(2009-07-06, 2010-06-10, 2013-01-22, 2005-03-09, 2008-06-09, 2008-11-07))
(418500000-01,CompactBuffer(2007-07-09, 2011-02-16, 2012-10-16, 2005-10-18, 2009-05-11, 2008-01-22, 2014-07-08, 2010-01-04, 2009-03-23, 2013-08-16))
```

I am trying to get the earliest date from the buffer, but I am getting an error from my code.

Code:

```
val t1RDD = t1RDD2.reduceByKey((date1, date2) => if (date1.before(date2)) date1 else date2)
```

Error:

```
value before is not a member of Iterable[java.sql.Date]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your `t1RDD2` is equivalent to the result of `groupByKey` on a PairRDD, as follows (with stripped-down sample data):

```
import java.sql.Date

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("000471242-01", Date.valueOf("2012-05-07")),
  ("000471242-01", Date.valueOf("2006-11-15")),
  ("996006688-01", Date.valueOf("2011-01-18")),
  ("996006688-01", Date.valueOf("2005-08-19")),
  ("996006688-01", Date.valueOf("2008-08-27"))
))

val t1RDD2 = rdd.groupByKey
// t1RDD2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[java.sql.Date])] = ...

t1RDD2.collect
// res1: Array[(String, Iterable[java.sql.Date])] = Array(
//   (996006688-01,CompactBuffer(2011-01-18, 2005-08-19, 2008-08-27)),
//   (000471242-01,CompactBuffer(2012-05-07, 2006-11-15))
// )
```

If you want to get the earliest date per key from `t1RDD2`, use `map` to `reduce` the value column for the minimal value:

```
t1RDD2.map{ case (k, v) => ( k, v.reduce((min, d) => if (min.before(d)) min else d) ) }.
  collect
// res2: Array[(String, java.sql.Date)] = Array((996006688-01,2005-08-19), (000471242-01,2006-11-15))
```

But it would be better to directly perform `reduceByKey` from the pre-grouped RDD, if applicable:

```
rdd.reduceByKey( (min, d) => if (min.before(d)) min else d ).
  collect
// res3: Array[(String, java.sql.Date)] = Array((996006688-01,2005-08-19), (000471242-01,2006-11-15))
```

Comment: Correct, Leo C! Particularly the last point. Where you state, "better to directly perform reduceByKey from the pre-grouped RDD." That's how I was able to solve my dilemma.

Comment: @Al., good to see that you can resort to using `reduceByKey` rather than `groupByKey` for [performance reason](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html).